# How to stretch component to fullscreen, even notch in reactnative

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, fullscreen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReAED.jpg

Hi, can somebody help me, how to stretch component all over iPhone screen, even notch? If you look at that image, I would like to have it even, where clock and battery icons are.

I've already tried to use SafeAreaView, but it didn't work.

```
    const { isLoading, loadingError } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {isLoading && this.renderLoading()}
        {
          loadingError
            ? this.renderLoadingError()
            : <WebView
              style={styles.radar}
              onLoad={this.onLoaded}
              onLoadStart={this.loadingStarted}
              onLoadEnd={this.onLoadFinished}
              onError={this.onError}
              source={{ uri: this.props.radarUrl }}
            />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Thank you in advice!

Comment: What is your style.container?

Comment: `container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  }`

Comment: i didn't work with IOS yet but i know you can hide those `battery, clock , ...` with this code, so try it and plz share the outcome with me: `<StatusBar
                        hidden={true}
                    />`